# Center div with unknows hegiht vertically with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a simple bootstrap column with height that takes half of the page (problem number one) the only method that I manged to do it is with jquery
dynamically change the height (I am sure that there is another way more elegant)...

**now to the main problem**...

after solving the height problem I am trying to vertically center another box from another column that  will be on the left side on the middle of the main box
please help me with this issue...

here is what I manged to do so far - [code](http://www.bootply.com/V88jx1oZXG)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2  col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-2" id="blue_box">            
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="red_box">
  </div>


</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
build_red_box();


});


function build_red_box(){
        $(window).height();
        $("#red_box").css("height",0.5*$(window).height());
        $("#blue_box").css("height",0.25*$("#red_box").height());
    }
```

**CSS**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
#red_box{
background-color:#F00;
}
#blue_box{
height:20px;
background-color:#009;

}
```

thanks a lot to the helpers :-)

Comment: You can always get height of the redbox and height of the blue box. Then you can count padding-top and set it in the script. I don't see better solution for now.

Comment: yeah that's what I did... isn't there is a more elegant way for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about poor souls using  IE8 and below, then use display: flex;

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9trje93/1/)

Centered content, **no JS**. Only CSS + HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="someItem">
        <p>Perfectly centered content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```